# Kotlin - execute statement and mask original exception thrown by statement

Tags: exception, kotlin

**Problem**

I'm using Java Reflection API to create new instance of a `Data` class:

```
val targetObject = Class.forName(sourceObject.javaClass.name).getConstructor().newInstance()
```

Copiler never complains about `newInstance()` throwing exception. But while creating new instance of a `Data` class, it naturally throws `NoSuchMethodException: <init> []` exception since `Data` class doesn't have implicit zero argument constructor unless initial values are assigned or zero argument constructor manualy added.

This implementation is part of library and I want to let developer know what is going wrong and what should be done to solve problem by "overriding" `NoSuchMethodException` with custom body, otherwise developer won't get how to solve the problem. For example, letting developer know that `Data` class should either have zero argument constructor or default values.

**Solution**

Currently I'm passing the `sourceObject` object to a method and return new instance or null then with Elvis operator I "override" original exception:

```
val targetObject  = newIntanceOrNull(sourceObject) ?: throw NoSuchMethodException("Custom message")


// Rest of the code

fun newIntanceOrNull(sourceObject: Any): Any? = try {
    Class.forName(sourceObject.javaClass.name).getConstructor().newInstance()
} catch (e: NoSuchMethodException) {
    null
}
```

**What I'm looking for**

A **built-in** operator (or a function) similar to Elvis operator but for Exceptions. Say, the left-hand side of the operator fails due to an exception then the right-hand side should be executed.

Comment: It seems to me `try-catch` is pretty much already the function you are asking for (except for not being a function). If it isn't, what do you want to do differently?

Comment: An operator similar to Elvis but for Exceptions. Say, the left-hand side of the operator fails due to an exception then the right-hand side should be executed. I think I have to edit last part of my question to make it a little clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Result](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html) from Kotlin standard library:

```
runCatching { /*your code*/ }.getOrNull()
```

Comment: And yes, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about such built-in function in Kotlin. I'm think that there is no such function in Kotlin's standard library but you can write it by yourself. I wrote an example of it. It's just a wrapper on top of `try-catch` but it might be more readable in some cases I guess:

```
inline infix fun <T> Function0<T>.orDo(recovery: (Throwable) -> T): T = try {
    invoke()
} catch (e: Throwable) {
    recovery(e)
}

fun error(): String = throw RuntimeException()

fun success(): String = "test"

fun main() {
    val val1 = { success() } orDo { throw RuntimeException("test", it) }
    println(val1) // prints "test"
    val val2 = { error() } orDo { throw RuntimeException("test", it) } // fails with exception
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely much better. But what I'm looking for is Kotlin's built-in function (or operator) with the exact same purpose. Anyway, I believe, I'll just go with my simple implementation. If you're quite sure that there is no such built-in function, please state it in your answer, so I can accept it

Comment: I'd just change to `recovery: (Throwable) -> T`, so you could do `{ throw RuntimeException("test", it) }` (your current example wouldn't change).

Comment: @Farid I know nothing about such built-in function